# ActionController::ParameterMissing at /accounts/deposit tieing params to deposit form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have been working on this rails 4 project since yesterday at 3pm and i have not slept. i am all out of ideas as to why this is bombing out. the error message i get is :                                                                           ActionController::ParameterMissing at /accounts/deposit
param is missing or the value is empty: affiliates_account

my accounts_controller looks like this:

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
#before_action :set_account, only: [:show, :edit, :deposit, :credit,     
:update, :destroy]
before_filter :set_account, only: [:show, :edit, :credit, :update, :destroy]
before_filter :authenticate_user!

respond_to :html

def index
 # @accounts = Account.all
 #@accounts = Account.where(id:current_user.id)
 if current_user.admin?
  @accounts = Account.all
  else
   @accounts = Account.where(email:current_user.email)
  end
  respond_with(@accounts)
  end

  def show
  if current_user.admin?
    @accounts = Account.all
   else
   @accounts = Account.where(email:current_user.email)
  end
  respond_with(@account)
  end

  def new
     @account = Account.new
     respond_with(@account)
  end

  def edit
    @accounts = Account.all
  end

  def create
    #  @account = Account.new(account_params)
    #@account.save
    # respond_with(@account)
  end

  def update
    @account.update(account_params)
    respond_with(@account)
  end

  def destroy
     @account.destroy
     respond_with(@account)
  end

  def withdrawl
    @account = Account.new(account_params)
    @account.email = current_user.email
    @account.user_id = current_user.id
  end

  def deposit
    @account = Account.new(account_params)
    @account.email = current_user.email
    @account.user_id = current_user.id
    respond_to do |format|
    @account.save
   end
     redirect_to :root
   end 


     private
     def set_account
        #@accounts = Account.where(id:current_user.id)
        @account = Account.find(params[:id])
     end

     def account_params
       # params[:account]
       params.require(:account).permit(:created_at, :email, :credit, :debit,
       :acctbal, :depotype)
     end
     end
```

and my Model for accounts.rb

```
 class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 validates :depotype, presence: true
 DEPOSIT_TYPES = [ "Check", "Credit card", "Purchase order" ]
 validates :depotype, inclusion: DEPOSIT_TYPES

 def final_acct_bal 
   accounts.to_a.sum {|account| account.final_acct_price}
   end
 end
```

and i created a new deposit.html.erb because the new.html.erb kept giving me a weird error and someone mention that the create method is tied to that and that i should create a seperate form page. so i did and now im having a tough time linking my deposit action method to that page so that my "add funds" button on my index.html.erb will go to it. and perform the requested actions accordingly.

```
<h1>Editing account</h1>

<%= render 'form' %>

<%= link_to 'Show', @account %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', accounts_path %>
```

my index.html.erb with that link_to button

```
<div class="container">
<h1>Listing Accounts Inquiries</h1>

<h2>Your Account information</h2>
  <table border="3">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Credit</th>
                <th>Debit</th>
                <th>Account Balance</th>
            </tr>
    </thead>
        <tbody>      
             <% @accounts.each do |account| %>   
                <tr>
                    <td><%= account.created_at %></td>
                    <td><b><font color="green"><%=
                         number_to_currency(account.credit)%></b></td>      
                    <td><b><font color="red"><%= 
                         number_to_currency(account.debit)%></font></b></td>    
                    <td><b><%= number_to_currency(account.acctbal)%></b>
               </td>        
                </tr>
                 <% end %>
            <tbody>     
        </table>
    </table>

    <%= link_to "Add Funds", deposit_accounts_path, method: :post, :class =>
       "btn btn-primary btn-sm" %>

    <table>
    <thead>
  <tr>
  <th colspan="3"></th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
     <% if can? :manage, Users%>
     <tbody>
       <% @accounts.each do |account| %>
      <tr>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', account %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_account_path(account) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', account, method: :delete, data: { confirm:
         'Are you sure?' } %></td>
       </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
  </table>

  <br>

   </div>
  <% end %>
```

i think this part of the params is hosing it up, params.require(:account) but i dont know what to do to change this so that it works and nothing else breaks

here is the Parameter Log

Started POST "/__better_errors/08542fc78df5081e/variables" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-04-25 13:31:29 -0400

Started POST "/accounts/deposit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-04-25 13:33:56 -0400
Processing by AccountsController#deposit as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"96gx+hIldjDtDpPKJAa3fwx/v9ooL1Y1xt5pNzFrC8U="}
  [1m[36mUser Load (1.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1[0m
Completed 400 Bad Request in 58ms

ActionController::ParameterMissing - param is missing or the value is empty: account:
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb:187:in `require'
  app/controllers/accounts_controller.rb:80:in`account_params'
  app/controllers/accounts_controller.rb:62:in `deposit'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in`send_action'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in`process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in`call'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in`block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in`block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in`block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in`block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in`block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in`block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in`block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in`block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in`run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in`process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in`block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in`instrument'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in`process_action'
  activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in`process'
  actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in`dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:232:in`block in action'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in`dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:73:in`block in call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in`call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:678:in `call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in`block in call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in`call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in`call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in`call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in`context'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in`call'
  activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in`call'
  activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/migration.rb:380:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in`block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in`call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in`call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in`better_errors_call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in`call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in`call_app'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in`block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in`tagged'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  quiet_assets (1.1.0) lib/quiet_assets.rb:27:in`call_with_quiet_assets'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in`call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in`call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:84:in`call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in`call'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in`call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in`service'
  c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in`run'
  c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'

Started POST "/__better_errors/19a4122f55bc057b/variables" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-04-25 13:33:57 -0400

my routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do


devise_for :users
get 'admin' => 'admin#index'
get 'users/index'
get 'accounts/index'

get 'accounts/show'

resources :students

root 'store#index', as: 'store'


 resources :orders

 resources :line_items

 resources :carts

 get 'store/index'

 resources :menus
 resources :users

 resources :accounts do
   collection do
    post 'deposit', :action => :deposit
    post 'withdrawl', :action => :withdrawl

  end
 end
```

Comment: Can you post server parameter logs to understand it better?, am sure account parameter is not getting passed to deposit method or your are reading it wrongly

Comment: where can i post it this comment box has a limit of 600 characters

Comment: Instead adding it as comment edit your answer

Comment: If you see parameters has its not having `account` in it., Are you sure all `before_filter` are correct? you might use `before_action`

Comment: i dont know if before_filter is right, i had help with it last night but i had issues with before_action thats why i commented it out. i got it to work when i changed params.require(:account).permit(:created_at, :email, :credit, :debit, :acctbal, :depotype) to                                                                  params.permit(:created_at, :email, :credit, :debit, :acctbal, :depotype) but validator went off for the dropdown and when i clicked the submit i got a template error

Comment: the last guy said this :  
Maybe because it is expecting params[:account] as you are putting in when creating your new account, but in your view you have no form setting these parameters, so you either need to create a form to set the parameters via user input, or in the controller don't use account_params, just use .new() and set the account objects variables manually

Comment: Can you post the routes corresponding to the action?

Answer (score 0):

Is this correctly posted in question?

```
#before_action :set_account, only: [:show, :edit, :deposit, :credit,     
:update, :destroy]
before_filter :set_account, only: [:show, :edit, :credit, :update,     :destroy]
before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

first `before_action` is commented and having `:deposit`

You should replace before_filter with before_action as its Rails 4, though before_action works, like

```
before_action :set_account, only: [:show, :edit, :deposit, :credit, :update, :destroy]
```

Your deposit method needs @account, so :set_account needs to be added in before_action

Comment: it gives me a different error, ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound at /accounts/deposit
Couldn't find Account without an ID and it point to a set_account method above params:                                                                                                       private
    def set_account
      #@accounts = Account.where(id:current_user.id)
      @account = Account.find(params[:id])
    end

Comment: do i need to pass the current_user_id somewhere ?

Comment: No if you are using devise and user is logged in then current_user is present, also if parameter has `:id` then `@account = Account.find(params[:id])` should work, its not issue with `before_action`, your routing or passing parameter is wrong somewhere double check your view code.

Comment: route seems correct, You should submit form for `account`  to deposit method, follow some good tutorial.

Comment: im new to rails, do you know any of good tutorials that can help me in my particular problem ?

Comment: This might help you http://ruby-on-rails.wonderhowto.com/how-to/create-admin-user-crud-ruby-rails-3-407821/ or always good to refer http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html